# Creating template with h3 block (block editor)

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I'm trying to register a custom post type with a template containing a preformated `h2` and `h3`. When I add a `core/heading` block, it automatically create a `H2`. What parameter should I add in order to have a `H3`?

My code looks like this:

```
register_post_type('custom-post', array(
  // [...]
  'template' => array(
    array(
      'core/heading',
       array(
         'placeholder' => 'this is a H2'
       )
    ),
    array(
      'core/heading',
      array(
        'heading' => '3', // this does not work
        'placeholder' => 'this should be a H3'
      )
    )
  )
));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out the solution: use `'level' => 3` as parameter.

```
register_post_type('custom-post', array(
  // [...]
  'template' => array(
    array(
      'core/heading',
      array(
        'level' => 3
        'placeholder' => 'this is a H3'
      )
    )
  )
));
```